# Access iPhone Photo App via Web Page

Tags: iphone

I'm developing a web version of a web page and the client wants to be able to view the images with the same options as in the photo app (Zoom, turn around, etc)

All this is from inside an iphone app that calls the web page.

The web page is a blog style page, where he uploads images of the work he does, so you get text and images, when you click the image is there a way to open the image in the photo app and not in a different page where you can't zoom in or zoom out?

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think there is actually a way to do this.

However, you can use some Javascript and built in CSS transforms to help make it behave more like the Photos application that ships with the iPhone.

If you go here http://developer.apple.com/videos/wwdc/2010/ and log in with any Apple developer account (free included), there is a video on how to do something similar to this. Under the "Internet and Web" section, check out session 508. They talk about how do something very similar to this.

Comment: Thanks, with the video I can do what I need.

Comment: I can't find session 508, can you tell me the name of the session, or provide a link?

Answer (score 0):

Checking the iOS documentation seems to indicate you cannot launch the photo app directly via a URL (http://developer.apple.com/library/safari/#featuredarticles/iPhoneURLScheme_Reference/Introduction/Introduction.html)

The best you could do would be to save the image in the user's Album or Camera Roll and let them launch the Photo app themselves. I know that "Wallpaper" apps take this approach.